# Avoid animation of AirPlay button in MPVolumeView

Tags: macos, animation, delay, airplay

I am developing an iPhone application that supports AirPlay using MPMoviePlayerController. When the user click on the play button Player custom View is added to a window. Hence didMoveToWindow is getting called. In this method I create MPMoviePlayerController and load it into custom player view.

I set allowsAirPlay of MPMoviePlayerController to YES. Add MPVolumeView to my custom Player view by removing all the volume related controls from MPVolumeView except AirPlay Control.

The problem is that AirPlay control appears after small delay of player loaded. Why does this happen? Is it because of animation added to AirPlay button? If so, how do I avoid this animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no [appstore safe] way to disable or interact with that animation.